# Reducing complex .Where with repeated actions in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a search function that applies successive `.Where` functions to a Entity Framework query based on potential parameters. One of these functions matches any item that has a difference between max and min values from a relational table over a certain amount. Uses the formula (x-y)/((x+y)/2) to calculate difference.

Finding the max and min from the relational table is quite expensive, and is repeated in the current query. This works, but is slow and I feel like I'm doing something wrong;

```
records = records.Where(x => x.FoodItems.Count(
    y =>
    y.Updates.Min(u => u.QuantityGrams) > 0 &&
    (
        y.Updates.Where(u => u.Action == RecordHistory.UpdateTypes.Quantify).GroupBy(u => u.User.Id).Max(u => u.OrderByDescending(z => z.Time).FirstOrDefault().QuantityGrams) -
        y.Updates.Where(u => u.Action == RecordHistory.UpdateTypes.Quantify).GroupBy(u => u.User.Id).Min(u => u.OrderByDescending(z => z.Time).FirstOrDefault().QuantityGrams)
    ) /
    (
        (
            y.Updates.Where(u => u.Action == RecordHistory.UpdateTypes.Quantify).GroupBy(u => u.User.Id).Max(u => u.OrderByDescending(z => z.Time).FirstOrDefault().QuantityGrams) +
            y.Updates.Where(u => u.Action == RecordHistory.UpdateTypes.Quantify).GroupBy(u => u.User.Id).Min(u => u.OrderByDescending(z => z.Time).FirstOrDefault().QuantityGrams)
        ) / 2
    )
    > gvDbl
    ) > 0);
```

Any way to reformat this so I don't need to get min/max twice, or speed it up somehow?

Comment: That query is .... hard to follow. You might need a view / FromSql that returns some `(id, min, max)` so you can join to that.

Comment: Is `RecordHistory.UpdateTypes.Quantify` a value in your local process, or a value in the database? Is `RecordHistory` a table in the database?